# How to throw exception when input stream has chars outside the ISO-8859-1 range

Tags: java, xml, exception, xml-parsing

I need to replace non ISO-8859-1 chars with configuured chars in inputStream (InputStream is created upon the XML file).
So i need to know how to throw exception when non ISO-8859-1 chars are available in InputStream.
Please suggest.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean. Does the InputStream actually contain UTF-8 encoded data, and you want to convert that to ISO-8859-1, throwing an exception if there are characters outside the set that can be encoded with ISO-8859-1? Bear in mind that an `InputStream` contains bytes, not characters - you want a `Reader` for characters... and if you don't know the encoding of the data, you'd have to probe the start of it in the same way as an XML parse in order to determine it.

Comment: XML may contain any encoding data mostly its UTF-8 only but i have concern when 0X84 and 0X96 chars which are not ISO-8859 chars and those has to be replaced or removed from XML before processing to DB layer. Also we create Document using InputStream or we can also create Reader using InputStream. BUt i want to know how i can catch or throw exception when chars are out of ISO-8859-1 range.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by 0X84 and 0X96, but *all* characters in the range U+0000 to U+00FF are valid characters in ISO-8859-1, although U+0080 to U+009F are control characters. Did you actually mean you're seeing *bytes* 0x84 and 0x96? If so, and if that's within a UTF-8-encoded document, they're probably only *parts* of characters. This is why it's so important to distinguish between bytes and characters...

Comment: 0X84 is &#x84; („)and 0x96 is &#x96; (–) which are not ISO-8859-1 chars

Comment: @JonSkeet actually not _all_ the range 0x00 - 0xFF is valid in ISO-8859-1: just have a look at the [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8859-1)

Comment: @morgano: Yes, I did - I checked it before I stated that. "In 1992, the IANA registered the character map ISO_8859-1:1987, more commonly known by its preferred MIME name of ISO-8859-1 (note the extra hyphen over ISO 8859-1), a superset of ISO 8859-1, for use on the Internet. This map assigns the C0 and C1 control characters to the unassigned code values thus provides for 256 characters via every possible 8-bit value."

Comment: hitts the way you are parsing that XML is wrong, as @JonSkeet said, you need to differentiate between chars and bytes. For instance, if you get, say the UTF-8 codified 'Ñ' it has two raw bytes: 0xC3, 0x91, if you do what you're doing, you'll wrongly take these two bytes as one char 'Ã' and other "invalid"

Comment: @JonSkeet granted, you're right; let me rephrase then: not all the range has a graphic printable representation